# Load balancing Vs MyMethod

Tags: load-balancing, web-farm

I am planning to move one of my websites to a web farm (only 2 servers). I understand the basic concept of how load balancing works but need help with 2 different ideas I have.

- Load balancing with webfarm

  - I am worried about SEO, duplicate content, different IP's?
- My method

The most of the resource consumption on my server is due to a long heavy memory process for every query. I have in mind to set up a different server (not with a website). Create web services for the heavy memory processes and call these webmethods from my main server. If need be I can add another a 3rd server and replicate the same web methods on it and multiply.

The only downside I see is that; before every call to the webmethod, I need to write an algorithm to find the server with most memory available and call the webmethod on that server.

Any ideas if this is a sound idea?

Lastly, quite a bit of resources are used on my main server due to large file uploads. Is there a way to counter and redirect this to the low memory usage server?

Regards,
Prasad..

Comment: When your websites are behind load balancer they are seen as one web address. Only load balancer knows that behind it there are multiple servers.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Can you lead me to some more reading on this concept? windows environment. The problem is by reading a lot of methods, I am getting confused.